# ASP - How to run a query on all connection strings listed in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, web-config, odbc

I have several connection strings defined in web.config, e.g.

```
<add 
  name="exampleConnStr"
  connectionString="Driver=ODBCDriver;server=blah;"
  providerName="Systerm.Data.Odbc"
/>
```

I'm drowning in MSDN documentation (which doesn't seem very good quality if I'm honest). What I'm trying to do is execute the same query against all of the databases defined within the web.config from an ASP page.

Can anyone show an example or provide search criteria likely to give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: If this is classic asp then my answer may not work.  Also, you should really not mark something as 2 different frameworks when you are only using one of them.

Comment: The only time it makes sense to use [tag:asp.net] and [tag:asp-classic] together on the same question is if you're trying to convert some code from one to the other. Otherwise, asp.net and asp-classic are about as similar as Java and JavaScript, which is to say, not at all.

Comment: ASP,net and Classic ASP use different connection strings for the same database, and in classic it's standard practice to store them in an include or as application variables in global.asa. web.config is for .net connection strings. www.connectionstrings.com is a useful resource

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell this is a very straight forward task.  You will need to use the System.Configuration namespace for this.

```
using System.Configuration;

  string conString;
  for (int i = 0; i < ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count; i++)
  {
       conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[i].ConnectionString;

       // No point to the conString variable, just showing how to access the connectionstring.
   }
```

Comment: this answer is for asp.net since you listed that as a tag.  I just now realized your question is only for asp.  I do not know anything about asp specifically.  I will delete this answer if necessary.

Comment: I suspect they mean from a ASP.Net page because the connection strings section they provided is for ADO.Net which isn't easily accessible in Classic ASP (or rather it's not accessible unless you put a COM wrapper around it which I have done).  I think you answer is likely a correct one.

Comment: Error: `System.Configuration` is a namespace and cannot be used as an expression`

Comment: You need to clarify if you're using asp or asp.net.  If you don't have that library or know how to add it then I assume you're using asp, and I can't give you any extra help with that.  Please correct your question and tags.

Comment: @AdamHeeg I'm a long time gone from ASP (pre 2000s). I'm pretty sure I'm using ASP classic, is there a definitive test I can do to prove this, or some other way to tell?

Comment: I have only used asp.net.  I don't know what you are using and I don't understand how you don't know. Sorry...

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche Do the pages finish with .asp (Classic-asp) or .aspx (asp.net)?